# Editing and formatting box plot in ggplot2-R (removing columns and box width in time series plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How to remove the **NA** column from my plot (inside red circle)?. Also, how to fix the width of box plots for the year 2021 (inside a blue circle) similar to the size as that of the previous years (from 2013 to 2019)?  My data structure has 577 rows and 27 columns. Although for some of the parameters, I have ‘NA’ values. However, for orthophosphate (figure attached), I do not have any NA values. Thank you. The R code shown below

```
p<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=Year, y=Ortho.P..µM,fill=factor(Season2))) +
  geom_boxplot()

p + labs(title = "clark", x = "Year", y = "Orthophosphate(µM), 
  Surface")+scale_fill_discrete(name = "Season")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=14))
```

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample of your data with  `dput`

Comment: @ Vinícius Félix when I copy and paste data structure obtained using dput function into the "Add comment" of stack overflow  it says "Too long by 174 characters"

Comment: Try `xlim(NA, 2021)`, also see the limits documentation. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html

Comment: Don't add your `dput` function into the add comments, directly add it to your question using the edit question button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I don't have the data, I guess this shoud work

### To fix the width of box plots

Add a argument to preserve the width inside the function `geom_boxplot`

`geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))`

### To remove the NA column

Before the `ggplot` filter the NA in `Year`

```
filter(!is.na(Year))
```

### Final Solution

```
df2 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Year)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Ortho.P..µM,fill=factor(Season2))) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))+
  labs(
    title = "clark",
    x = "Year",
    y = "Orthophosphate(µM), Surface")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Season")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=14))
```